# Regular expression for not allowing special chars at the end including underscore and with only 3 character limit

Tags: java, android, regex, special-characters, pcre

1. My Requirement is "Name should **begin** with an alphabet and should have atleast **three** chars and  cannot **end** with a special character,But the special chars can come in the **middle** ." It should not allow underscore at the end also.
2. Regex that I am using  `[a-zA-Z][\w]{1,}.*[\w]`
3. The above regex not recognise underscore`(_)` as special char at the end.
4. when I type "sss_" its not recognising.
5. when i type "sss@" or "sss#" or "sss$" its recognising.
6. The expected result "test", "test@test", "test_test", "tes"
7. unexpected result "tes@", "test_", "te"

Comment: `\w` matches a `_`. Replace with `[^\W_]` to "exclude" (or as it is called, "subtract") the `_` from `\w`. Note that `.*` matches any 0+ chars (other than line breaks).

Comment: What can there be inside? Just letters? ASCII or Unicode as well? Which tag is valid: JS or PCRE ????

Comment: yeah its working but if i give eg like a_a, team_testing, its not working . it should allow underscore in those cases.

Comment: Ok, so the rule is: `letters` + ( `_` + `letters`) `*`, right? Now, is it JS or PCRE? should it support Unicode letters?

Comment: its pcre.. and it should allow unicode also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 2:

Since you now say it is in Android, remove `(?U)`. All shorthand character classes are already Unicode-aware in the Android regex:

```
"\\p{L}+(?:[\\W_]\\p{L}+)*"
```

And use it with `matches()`.

## Updated answer

Use

```
Boolean isValid = groupNameString.matches("(?U)\\p{L}+(?:[\\W_]\\p{L}+)*");
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/yvJETm).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(validateName("Dąb_rośnie$gdzieś#tu"));
        System.out.println(validateName("Some_string_here"));
    }
    private static boolean validateName(String name) { 
        if (name.matches("(?U)\\p{L}+(?:[\\W_]\\p{L}+)*")) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Note you do not even need anchors when using `String#matches()` since this method anchors the pattern by default.

The `[\\W_]` will match any special char *inlcuding* a `_`.

## Original answer

To match the  `letters` + ( `_` + `letters`) `*` pattern, you may use

```
 ^[^\W\d_]+(?:_[^\W\d_]+)*$
```

Instead of `[^\W\d_]`, you may use `[a-zA-Z]` in JS or any other engine that is not Unicode-aware and you need to handle ASCII letters only.

**The Unicode-aware equivalent**:

```
^\p{L}+(?:_\p{L}+)*$
```

Here, `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[^\W\d_]+` / `\p{L}+` - 1 or more letters
- `(?:_[^\W\d_]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `_` - a `_`
  - `[^\W\d_]+` / `\p{L}+` - 1 or more letters
- `$` - end of string anchor.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FMrMKu/1).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138401/discussion-on-answer-by-wiktor-stribizew-regular-expression-for-not-allowing-spe).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex expression

```
^[A-z]+[^\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\_|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s]+$
```